# Evaluation time of C# properties

Tags: c#, properties

```
class Bar
{
  private byte[] dg;

  Bar(byte[] datagram)
  {
    dg = datagram;
  }

  int Foo
  {
    get { return BitConverter.ToInt16(dg, 8); }
  }
}
```

When are properties evaluated? At the time Foo is accessed? The debugger evaluating all properties is scaring me.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to have a property getter do any extensive work, because someone using your code will assume evaluating the property will be a cheap operation. If that's not the case, use a `GetFoo()` method.

Comment: In that example I would do the conversion first and then save it to be returned in Foo.

Comment: @Ed Swangren Why save a bunch of conversions if most of them are never used or only used once.

@Thorarin I agree a method would be much nicer. But with good documentation the property will be just fine. If people want to put something as dumb as properties in a language then I'm going to use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a property is just syntactic sugar for the call to `get` accessor method. Every time property is read, the method executes. And yes, this does include the debugger (which is why if your property gettors have side effects, debugging can actually affect the way your program works).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C# properties are simply syntactic sugar for specialized methods so they are evaluated when called, like any other type of instance method.